# SignalR client HubConnection Stop

Tags: client, signalr

I have malicious problem with stopping connection in SignalR client.

Here we go with my code.

I start connection with simple method

```
private void Initialize()
    {
        var hermesHubAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HermesUrl"];
        _hubConnection = new HubConnection(hermesHubAddress)
        {
            Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        };

        _hubProxy = _hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("HermesHub");
        _hubProxy.On<Notification>("Notify", Recieve_Message);
        _hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        _hubConnection.Error += HubConnectionOnError;
        _hubConnection.StateChanged += HubConnectionOnStateChanged;
    }
```

then when client performs an action to close connection

```
public void Stop()
    {
        _hubConnection.Stop();
        _hubConnection.Dispose();
    }
```

Event listner noticed connection state changed and invoked action

```
private void HubConnectionOnStateChanged(StateChange stateChange)
    {
        if (stateChange.NewState == ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            if (ConnectionEvent != null)
                ConnectionEvent.Invoke(true);
        }
        else
        {

            if (ConnectionEvent != null)
                ConnectionEvent.Invoke(false);
        }
    }
```

everything works fine and client is disconnected but when SignalR server broadcasts message somehow _hubProxy autoreconnect to the server and gets response.

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one message to be sent SignalR will try to group them send in one payload. This is the reason why `M` is an array (you can find more about SignalR protocol in [my post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/)).

SignalR cannot send just one message per poll. Polling can be really slow since the client needs to create a new HTTP request for one poll. If you get messages faster than the interval between polls you wouldn't be able to keep up if you sent just one message per poll and you will start missing messages.